# How to fix vim minibufexplorer buffer ordering?

Tags: vim-plugins

Say I open 4 files in vim with minibufexplorer plugin installed. I get:

```
[1:file1][2:file2][3:file3][4:file4]
```

Now I close file 2 with `:bd2` (buffer delete 2):

```
[1:file1][3:file3][4:file4]
```

And reopen it again:

```
[1:file1][3:file3][4:file4][2:file2]
```

See that file2 is now at the end. The problem is that if I have file1 opened and I enter `:bn` (buffer next), I expect to jump to file3 instead of file2 (because file1 is highligted). This is inconvenient, as I am no longer able to tell if I can use `:bn` by a short glance at the header.

I remember that some time ago the plugin would place `[file2]` between `[file1]` and `[file3]`, the place where it should be. How do I configure it to do so again? I checked readme at [github](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/blob/master/doc/minibufexpl.txt) but there seems to be no mention of this feature. `:MBEToggleMRU` does not achieve the desired effect.

I have vim version 8.1 and plugin version 6.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this is an already known bug in the plugin. There is a pull request to fix it in its repository: https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/pull/127

As the plugin seems to not be maintained anymore I use version from thasmin (author of the pull request) located here: https://github.com/thasmin/minibufexpl.vim